# Linq Order By String Not Working

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities, sql-order-by, predicate

I can't understand why this code won't order my list of data by string name.

```
public class GroupedRow
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public decimal SumOfDays { get; set; }
}

var data = _dataService.GetData();

List<GroupedRow> result = data
    .GroupBy(l => l.listItemID.Value)
    .Select(cl => new GroupedRow
    {
        label = cl.First().ListItem.description,
        SumOfDays = cl.Sum(c => c.timeAssigned.Value) / 8.0m
    }).ToList();

result.OrderByDescending(x => x.label).ToList();
```

I am trying to order the list by label which is a string, however, it never works.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are ordering the list and creating the new list using the `ToList()` but you are not assigning return value to anything so you lose it. Eiter fix it by:

```
result = result.OrderByDescending(x => x.label).ToList();
```

or

```
List<GroupedRow> result = data
    .GroupBy(l => l.listItemID.Value)
    .Select(cl => new GroupedRow
    {
        label = cl.First().ListItem.description,
        SumOfDays = cl.Sum(c => c.timeAssigned.Value) / 8.0m
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.label)
    .ToList();
```